# How to add a new user in a PL/SQL table using a function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am fairly new to PL/SQL and one of the doubts I have is to create and declare functions.
Specifically this one:

Create a function that creates a new user:

1. Use a sequence togive the new User a new ID
2. Pass the name, address, etc... as IN arguments
3. Return as OUT arguments the ID created and a O_ERROR_MESSAGE
4. Function returns TRUE if the user is added, otherwise returns FALSE
5. Handle exceptions
6. Create a PL/SQL  block and test the created function

This is my code so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS (I_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_BIRTHDATE IN DATE,
                                                I_COUNTRY IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    O_ERROR_MESSAGE EXCEPTION;
    CURRENT_USER NUMBER;

BEGIN

DSB_NB_SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL;
SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) INTO CURRENT_USER
FROM DSB_NB_USERS;

WHILE CURRENT_USER != 0
LOOP
DSB_NB_SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL;
SELECT COUNT(USER_ID) INTO CURRENT_USER
FROM DSB_NB_USERS;
END LOOP;

INSERT INTO DSB_NB_USERS (USER_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, BIRTHDATE, COUNTRY_ID_FK) VALUES (CURRENT_USER, I_NAME, I_ADDRESS, TO_DATE('I_BIRTHDATE', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), I_COUNTRY);

RETURN CURRET_USER;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN O_ERROR_MESSAGE THEN 
    RETURN NULL;

    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;

DECLARE
    I_NEW_USER NUMBER;
BEGIN
    I_NEW_USER := DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS(I_NAME => 'Arnaldo Amaral',
                                    I_ADDRESS => 'Rua da Agra',
                                    I_BIRTHDATE => '03/05/1959',
                                    I_COUNTRY => 'PT');                                 
END;
```

Am i too far from the truth?
I know there's still a lot to add.

Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: Others may disagree, but I don't consider this to be a good use of a function.  I think it would be better suited to a procedure.  When I think of FUNCTION I think of things like to_char ... things that return a single value and intended to assign that single value either to a properly typed variable, or as part of the column projection of a query.

Comment: I expect the homework assignment calls specifically for a function.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson - yes, unfortunately that is something I/we see in all technical forums.  Someone asking for help on a school assignment, where the assignment may be meant to teach a very specific coding technique, but also teaches poor design practice.  Instructors fail to understand that when they give a student an exercise to teach, say, a 'cursor for loop', the student, lacking any other background, is also picking up on the context of the given exercise and assuming that it is acceptable application/system design.

Comment: @EdStevens, indeed, this is a homework request. You are not the first person saying the exact same thing. I tried to squeeze a bit more knowledge from my teacher but with this pandemic and 20 other students to review the code, gets a bit difficult.
I am on the road to learn a new skillset and by commiting these mistakes, is the best way to learn it 'cause then you will know what not to do.
Still, i thing this might be a question with a trap, it wouldn't be the first time the teacher would do something like this.
Thank you so much once again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are asking for a lifeline, that needs more than just a code response.  First off look at the answer by 
@Tejash. His solution is a far cry from what you have, and is correct for your function definition (although that is itself incorrect given your listed requirements.) Also, @EdStevens is correct that is is a very poor use of a function. However a function is your assignment's requirement.  
 
So lets dissect your code and see how it satisfies each of your requirements. (I cannot stand all caps, so I'm lower casing it.)

1. Fails.  While you have a sequence it is used improperly. You can not
   just code a standalone name. It must be used in either a SQL
   statement or an assignment statement.
2. Passes.
3. Fails. Your function passes the IN parameters correctly. However
   there are no OUT parameters.
4. Your function returns Number not the required True/False which
   requires either Boolean or varchar2 for literal.

   Code section for requirements 3,4.

```
create or replace function dsb_add_new_users (i_name in varchar2,
                                              i_address in varchar2,
                                              i_birthdate in date,
                                              i_country in varchar2)   <<< where are the 2 required out parameters
    return number is                                                   <<< Should be True or False so either Boolean or varchar2
    o_error_message exception;                                         <<< Should be an Out parameter not an exception
```

5. Yes you have the Exception Section, which is required for handling
   exceptions. However you do not handle exceptions so much as suppress
   them, indicating to Oracle, and to the calling routine, that they didn't actually happen.

```
exception
    when o_error_message then      <<< as coded this is a developer defined exception, yet is not raised so it cannot happen.
    return null;                   <<< even if it were raised you have thrown it away, the calling routine will never it happened

    when others then               <<< One of the worst pieces of code that can be written. I tend to remember seeing a discussion in 
    return null;                   <<< Oracle that would make this a compile time error. To bad the supporters lost the argument.
```

6. Passed, mostly. Correct for posted code, but insufficient per requirements.

So all-in-all not highly successful when viewed against the requirements.  
 
A couple other items not specific the requirements, but disaster to successful implementation.
While technically you might get away with the following it is very bad practice. Current_User is an [Oracle reserved word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/em.102/b40103/app_oracle_reserved_words.htm).

```
current_user number;   <<< NO, NO bad verifiable name.
```

The following completely decimates your function. It creates a never ending loop. Well not quite -- it runs 1 time, but never afterward.  
I believe you intended for the current_user variable to contain the ID assigned to the user. But it actually contains the number of rows in the table. Further what would the number of rows (count) have to do with Inserting a row? SO what does the code actually Do?

```
dsb_nb_seq_user_id.nextval;                <<< systax error. 
select count(user_id) into current_user    <<< count the number of rows in the table
from dsb_nb_users;

while current_user != 0                    <<< if there are any rows in the table 
loop
dsb_nb_seq_user_id.nextval;                <<< syntax  error 
select count(user_id) into current_user    <<< try counting then again until there are none.
from dsb_nb_users;
end loop;
```

So correcting for the above what do we wind up with. I hesitate here in fear you will just copy the below and submit it. Please don't do that but study and understand what it's doing, then rewrite you routine. But after tearing you initial effort up, I guess I owe a corrected solution.

```
create or replace function dsb_add_new_users 
                         ( i_name          in  varchar2
                         , i_address       in  varchar2
                         , i_birthdate     in  date
                         , i_country       in  varchar2
                         , o_new_user_id   out number
                         , o_error_message out varchar2
    return boolean 
is
    country_id_l  number;
begin
   -- initialize out variables
   o_new_user_id   := null;
   o_error_message := null;

   -- get country id from input parameter
   select country_id 
     into country_id_l
     from country
    where name = i_country;

   -- create user and get the assigned user_id

    insert into dsb_nb_users (user_id, name, address, birthdate, country_id_fk) 
         values dsb_nb_seq_user_id.nextval
              , i_name
              , i_address
              , i_birthdate
              , country_id_l
              )
      returning user_id
           into o_new_user_id;

    return true;

exception
    when no_date_found then 
        o_output_message = 'ERROR: Specified country name ''' || country_id_l || ''' Not Found.';
        return false;

    when others then
        o_output_message := 'ERROR: ' || sqlerrm;
        return false
end dsb_add_new_users ;


--------------- Test Driver ----------------
declare
    i_new_user       number;
    new_user_created boolean;
    error_message    varchar2(255);     
begin
    new_user_created := dsb_add_new_users( i_name          => 'Arnaldo Amaral',
                                         , i_address       => 'Rua da Agra' 
                                         , i_birthdate     => to_date('03/05/1959','mm/dd/yyyy')  -- or is it 'dd/mm/yyyy' 
                                         , i_country       => 'PT'
                                         , o_new_user_id   => i_new_user
                                         , o_error_message => error_message);
   if not new_user_created
   then 
       dbms_output.put_line (error_messag); 
   end if ; 
end;
```

**Disclaimer**: As you did not post table DDL nor test data the routine has not been tested nor even compiled. Any syntax error(s) is for you to resolve. Further, I follow Tejash in the assumption you actually have a countries table and there is a FK to it. That may be an erroneous assumption.

Comment: Worth mentioning that a function with OUT parameters is widely regarded as bad practice. It's a huge red flag that this ought to be a procedure.

Comment: Belayer, thank you so much for your input. No need to apologize or be affraid that i'll just copy paste this comment. That's not what i intended. I really want and need to understand this. Thank you for "trashing" my work to make me learn better practices.
I will continue to study this block of code to try to understand where i am making the mistakes and solve them.
Thank you so much once again!

Comment: :-)  mission accomplished :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly use the sequence value to insert new user as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS (
    I_NAME        IN            VARCHAR2,
    I_ADDRESS     IN            VARCHAR2,
    I_BIRTHDATE   IN            DATE,
    I_COUNTRY     IN            VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER IS
    CURRENT_USER_ID   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    CURRENT_USER_ID := DSB_NB_SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL; -- returns new and unique number
    INSERT INTO DSB_NB_USERS (
        USER_ID,
        NAME,
        ADDRESS,
        BIRTHDATE,
        COUNTRY_ID_FK
    ) VALUES (
        CURRENT_USER_ID,
        I_NAME,
        I_ADDRESS,
        I_BIRTHDATE,
        (
            SELECT
                COUNTRY_ID
            FROM
                COUNTRIES
            WHERE
                NAME = I_COUNTRY
        ) -- it is FK so need to use SELECT sub-query to find COUNTRY_ID
    );

    RETURN CURRENT_USER_ID; -- returning the new user ID
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN -1; -- returning -1 in case there is any error
END;
```

-1 will be returned when there is an error while adding the new user.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this much simpler answer after asking to a few people for help.

```
create or replace FUNCTION DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS (I_NAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_ADDRESS IN VARCHAR2,
                                                I_BIRTHDATE IN DATE,
                                                I_COUNTRY IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER IS
    CURRENT_USER NUMBER;

BEGIN
CURRENT_USER := DSB_NB_SEQ_USER_ID.NEXTVAL;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hello World');

INSERT INTO DSB_NB_USERS (USER_ID, NAME, ADDRESS, BIRTHDATE, COUNTRY_ID_FK) VALUES (CURRENT_USER, I_NAME, I_ADDRESS, TO_DATE(I_BIRTHDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), I_COUNTRY);
RETURN CURRENT_USER;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    RETURN -1;

END;

SET SERVEROUT ON
DECLARE
    I_NEW_USER NUMBER;
BEGIN
    I_NEW_USER := DSB_ADD_NEW_USERS(I_NAME => 'Arnaldo Amaral',
                                    I_ADDRESS => 'Rua da Agra',
                                    I_BIRTHDATE => '03/MAY/1959',
                                    I_COUNTRY => 'PT');       
                                    commit;


END;
/
```

Thank you all!!!